# Ajax loaded page refreshing when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I load a page in a div through AJAX. This works great.
On this ajax loaded page there are some buttons (generally created with javascript). When I click on one of these buttons the page refreshes. Weird thing is; no where I stated the page SHOULD refresh. Afterall; that's why I use ajax.

This is the javascript that's executed on the AJAX loaded page:

```
function buttonClicked(id){
    var page = id;
    photoPage = page*10;
    if(cur_button < id)
    {
        minCount += 10;
        maxCount += 10;
    }
    else
    {
        minCount -= 10;
        maxCount -= 10;
    }
    cur_button = id;
    jQuery("#imagesDiv").html("");
    $( "#imagesDiv" ).append( " <br/>");
    executePage();
}
function createButtons() {
    var i = 1;
    var button = "";
    while(i <= photoCount)
    {
        var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var buttonName = document.createTextNode(i);
        button.appendChild(buttonName);
        button.id = i;
        jQuery(button).bind('click', { id: i}, function(event) {
            var data = event.data;
            buttonClicked(data.id);
        });
        imagesDivJS.appendChild(button);
        i++;
    }
}
function executePage()
{
    setImagesDivID();
    createButtons();
    $( ids ).append( " <br/>");
    populateDiv();
}
    function populateDiv() {
        for(var i = minCount;i < maxCount; i++)
        {
            if(i < total_count)
            {
                create_image("../"+photos[i],photoAlts[i]);
                $("#"+ids).append( "<p style=\"display:inline; padding-left:10px;\">" + photoTags[i] + "</p><br/>" );
            }
        }
    }
```

Help will be appreciated. I've been breaking my neck around this thing!

Comment: Where is your `buttonClicked()` function?

Comment: I have added event.preventDefault() under the line with buttonClicked(data.id). Still refreshing. Same goes for  return false. When I typed event.preve and it let auto complete it said there was no auto completion possible, in other words; the method is unknown (?)

Comment: Try adding an attribute of type="button" to the button

Comment: just check the html generated by `createButtons()` method i think it is generating submit buttons instead of normal buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is refreshing the page because it is a submit button. You need to add an attribute of `type="button"` to the button. For example:

```
function createButtons() {
    var i = 1;
    var button = "";
    while(i <= photoCount)
    {
        var button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var buttonName = document.createTextNode(i);
        button.appendChild(buttonName);
        button.id = i;

        // Add type="button"
        button.setAttribute("type", "button");

        jQuery(button).bind('click', { id: i}, function(event) {
            var data = event.data;
            buttonClicked(data.id);
        });
        imagesDivJS.appendChild(button);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I thought the default type of a button... Would be a button. Thanks for your help!

Comment: haha yep you would think so! Just one of those things that you need to discover the hard way